# C++ can't call method

Tags: c++, templates, methods

I've got the following code and have no idea how I can call the AMethod() function. Can anyone help me with this? 
Thank you

```
template<>
class AClass < std::shared_ptr<AnObject> >
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<AnObject> AMethod() const
    {
        //DoStuff
        return std::make_shared<AnObject>(x);
    }
};
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
AClass < std::shared_ptr<AnObject> > instance(); 
 std::shared_ptr<AnObject> result = instance.AMethod();
```

I get "Error: Expression must have class type" on the second line on instance.

Comment: You need some instance to call a method on it. Your question is too broad, or unclear, and you really need to take a few days to read an entire book on [Programming in C++](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html); we cannot teach you that in an answer of a few paragraphs.

Comment: That's what I was thinking I tried the following but it didn't work:             AClass < std::shared_ptr<AnObject> > instance();
std::shared_ptr<AnObject> result = instance.AMethod();

Comment: Please edit your own question, don't comment it. Leave the comments to others

Comment: And things are different in C++11 (thanks to `auto`) and in older versions of the standard.

Comment: Why didn't that work? Give the error message of the compiler. BTW, your question is still unclear after your first edit, you'll better give a small selfcontained example, and show what exactly the `AClass` template is.

Comment: You can use `auto result = instance.AMethod();` (after fixing the other error as pointed out by Peter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AClass < std::shared_ptr<AnObject> > instance();
```

does not create an instance of `AClass < std::shared_ptr<AnObject> >`.

It declares a function named `instance()` which accepts no arguments and returns a `AClass < std::shared_ptr<AnObject> >`.

This is called, among other things, "the most vexing parse".

Remove the `()`.

Comment: Thanks alot, I feel so stupid now. Comming from Java it's not the first time I make this error. Thank you

Comment: That's okay.  It takes time to recover from Java  ;)